# Getting Error When trying to Import Data From Oracle to HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, sqoop

I am running below command to import data from Oracle Db to HIVE

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/newDB --username <USERNAME> --P --table <ORACLE_TABLE_NAME> --hive-table <HIVE_TABLE_NAME> --hive-import -m 1
```

I am getting below Error when i am running this Query

```
17/11/21 05:05:46 INFO oracle.OraOopManagerFactory: Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop is disabled.
17/11/21 05:05:46 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
17/11/21 05:05:46 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
17/11/21 05:05:47 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
17/11/21 05:05:47 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM "<TABLE_NAME>" t WHERE 1=0
17/11/21 05:05:47 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Imported Failed: There is no column found in the target table <TABLE_NAME>. Please ensure that your table name is correct.
```

Comment: Can you please check and confirm if the Oracle  user you are using has select access to the Oracle table?

Comment: @vishad The user has select access to the oracle tables.

Comment: try using `table_owner.table_name` for oracle source.

Comment: @SandeepSingh I tried table_owner.table_name its throwing java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: Can you run Sqoop import using  `--verbose` argument  and update question with the log you are getting.

Comment: due to a known bug in oracle `--table` option doesn't work properly with few oracle versions. Can you try with `--query` option as well to check this.

Comment: @SandeepSingh adding --query now its able to fetch the records but it is throwing a different error

Comment: java.io.IOException: SQLException in nextKeyValue
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:277)
     
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression

Answer (score 0):

Check the owner of table and try using `table_owner.table_name` for oracle source.

Answer (score 0):

I find you are not used --create-hive-table  and  few other parameter in your query.

Below is the sqoop import query i use in my project:

oracle_connection.txt will have the connection info.

```
sqoop --options-file  oracle_connection.txt \
--table $DATABASE.$TABLENAME \
-m $NUMMAPPERS  \
--where "$CONDITION" \
--hive-import \
--map-column-hive "$COLLIST" \
--create-hive-table \
--hive-drop-import-delims \
--split-by $SPLITBYCOLUMN  \
--hive-table $HIVEDATABASE.$TABLENAME \
--bindir sqoop_hive_rxhome/bindir/ \
--outdir sqoop_hive_rxhome/outdir
```